# android - How to set selected days highlighted in a calenderView, data from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, calendar

I have been developing an app with firebase database. In my app I had to use a calenderView in which selected dates has to be highlighted using the data form the firebase database.[image]

need to highlight the dates that is stored in the above node. my date format will be DD/MM/YYYY.

```
 CalenderView calendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.calenderView);

            nodes.getNodeDailyList().child("dateList").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       String date = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).replace(",","/");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select more than one day in you calendar view. 
You'd need either a library or a custom component. A library I'd recommend would be [MaterialCalendarView](http://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview).

In the library you can parse a date from string using this method:

```
public Date getDate(String date){

    String dateArray[] = date.split("/");

    int day = Integer.parseInt(dateArray[0]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(dateArray[1]);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(dateArray[2]);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);


    long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    return new Date(time);
}
```

You can then use the library `setDateSelected(Date date, boolean selected)` method to select a date.

Finally, the way your code is right now if your node has more than one date you'll have a problem. What you need to do is:

```
nodes.getNodeDailyList().child("dateList").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String date = snapshot.getValue(String.class).replace(",","/");

                    //do something with date
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: perfect dude... how to disable the dates which are not selected?

Comment: What do you mean by disable? Make them non clickable?

Comment: You can't, unless you hack the library :/ What you CAN do is use the OnDateSelectedListener, when the user clicks a forbidden date you simply deselect that date.

Comment: Dude... To make the selected days clickable, when a date is clicked I once again retrieved the data snapshot from the database and checked whether the selected date is in the database... This gives me the perfect result... Thank you, dude...